# What programming languages prevent null pointer exceptions?

Tags: null, nullpointerexception

I know that you can't get a null pointer exception in Haskell, but I'm curious about what other languages have this feature.  For example, a coworker asked if any interpreted languages disallow nulls and I didn't know the answer.  The only language I know of that avoids this [billion dollar mistake](http://qconlondon.com/london-2009/presentation/Null+References%3a+The+Billion+Dollar+Mistake) is Haskell.

Comment: PHP? Technically it doesn't give you a nullpointer exception, just a warning.

Comment: @BartFriederichs to me it doesn't sound like that avoids the "billion dollar mistake" but it's still very interesting to know

Comment: Actually you can peek/poke a nullPtr in Haskell (inside IO monad)

Answer (score 3):

In Objective-C, you can pass messages to objects that are actually `nil` and they silently return `nil` themselves.

But you can still be at risk of null pointer exceptions when you do C-like pointer dereferencing (i.e. when using the `*` or `.` operators).

Answer (score 0):

[Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) is a statically-typed programming language that runs on the Java virtual machine and also can be compiled to JavaScript source code or use the LLVM compiler infrastructure.

Kotlin avoids null pointer exceptions by making a distinction between nullable and non-nullable types. All nullable variables must be declared with a "?" postfix after the type name. Operations on nullable variables need special care from developers: null-check must be performed before using the value.

To call methods on a variable of nullable type, you must either use the "?" operator, which only calls the method if the variable is not null (and makes it's return type nullable), or the "!!" operator, which asserts that the variable is currently not null.

Note that you can still get null pointer exceptions on Kotlin if you use the "!!" operator on a null object or when doing interop with Java.

Answer (score 0):

C++ values and references cannot be null, only pointers can be. If you don't use pointers and in modern C++ seldomly you need to use it, you can avoid the problem entirely. Using static polymorphism is preferred to dynamic one. Dynamic polymorphism is strictly necessary only when the set of possible implementations is unknown at compile time. In this case, the null-object pattern or factory can avoid the null-pointer issue (an const keywords can help to prevent unwanted reassignement).